# jQuery conflict on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm encountering a problem.
On my page, I'd like to add a new piece of jQuery code which makes use of:

Somehow, when I add this script, my piece of code works, but the rest of the website code is broken.

I've tried to add the `$.noConflict(true);` script to my jquery. But it doesn't work somehow..
Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Hank

Comment: What script are you adding and how? How is the rest of the site broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is in noConflict mode by default, you don't have to add anything, you just have to use `jQuery`, and not `$`.

This is usually handled with jQuery wrappers

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // code here
});
```

It also means

```
$.noConflict(true);
```

won't work, as `$` is not defined in Wordpress, it's all explained in the [**Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: I don't get what to change really. Like I said, I'm new to jQuery - so  I don't have a clue.

Comment: You shouldn't change anything, and you don't have to mess with noConflict, just follow the codex and wrap jQuery code in the proper wrappers, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another variable to use instead of $ like `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new variable instead of the `$` and use that.

For example for wordpress u will use $

then for the other jquery you could create a new one like this

```
var jquery = $.noConflict();
```

For example
Now you will use jquery instead of $

```
jquery(document).ready(function (){
  var form = jquery('#formcomments');
  var submit = jquery('#comments');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert all `$` to `jQuery` in your code or use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   // Your code here
});
```

or put your code inside a closure:

```
(function($){
    // Your code here
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

$.noConflict();
add this function where your scripts is conflict